# How to write two types of information into nfc tag and make reader read them at the same time?

Tags: android, uri, wifi, nfc, ndef

I am working on a Mobile Programming project. The Mobile program aims to write uri information like http://example.com as uri payload and wifi credentials so that when you tap nfc tag you can connect to wifi and open up uri in the browser.

I have tested to write two information into one nfc tag but it does not seem to provide two operations at the same time.

If the project is successful on tap onto nfc tag the mobile has to popup wifi connection and open uri in the browser.
If anyone has the clue i will be so pleased to follow!

Answer (score 0):

NDEF message is composed of NDEF Records. In this case, the message should consist of 4 records namely:

1. URI Record Type representing http://example.com
2. Recommended Action Record
3. Title Record
4. **W**ifi **S**imple **C**onfiguration Record defined by **W**i-**F**i **A**lliance Mime Type being application/vnd.wfa.wsc ([Android Code that writes such record](http://androidxref.com/9.0.0_r3/xref/packages/apps/Settings/src/com/android/settings/wifi/WriteWifiConfigToNfcDialog.java))

NDEF message consisting of the first 3 records is as follows. Please update it to contain the 4th record yourself.
`----------
Offset Content      Length Explanation
    0   0xD1        1 NDEF header. TNF = 0x01(Well Known Type). SR=1, MB=1, ME=1
    1   0x02        1 Record name length (2 bytes)
    2   0x30        1 Length of the Smart Poster data (48 bytes)
    3   “Sp”        2 The record name
    5   0x81        1 NDEF header. TNF = 0x01, SR=0, MB=1, ME=0
    6   0x01        1 Record name length (1 byte)
    7   0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x0C   4 The length of the URI payload (12 bytes) (long format)
    11  “U”         1 Record type: “U”
    12  0x03        1 Abbreviation: “http://”
    13  “example.com”  11 The URI itself.
    24  0x11        1 NDEF record header (SR=1, TNF=0x01)
    25  0x03        1 The length of the record name
    26  0x01        1 The length of the “act” payload.
    27  “act”       3 Record type: “act”
    30  0x00        1 Action = Launch browser
    31  0x11        1 NDEF record header (SR=1, TNF=0x01)
    32  0x01        1 Length of the record name
    33  0x12        1 Length of the record payload (18 bytes)
    34  “T”         1 Record type: “T” (=Text)
    35  0x05        1 Status byte for the Text (UTF-8, five-byte code)
    36  “en-US”     5 ISO Language code: US-English
    41  “Hello, world” 12 The text: “Hello world”, encoded in UTF-8.
----------`

To answer your question of whether its possible to get the Android reader to handle these multiple records we should look at the [NFC Tag Dispatch system](http://androidxref.com/9.0.0_r3/xref/packages/apps/Nfc/src/com/android/nfc/NfcDispatcher.java)
This system creates an intent with
 - action = NfcAdapter.ACTION_NDEF_DISCOVERED
 - MimeType = mimetype of the first record
 - Intent's Extra NfcAdapter.EXTRA_NDEF_MESSAGES contains complete Ndef message
Therefore, Android populates mimetype of first record only.
**Its left to the application or service that picks up this intent to process all the NDEF records as needed.**

Comment: thank you for your in-depth explanation!
I already experienced that by default without any third party app native android nfc reader read the first encountered mime type. 
I was unable to make android read two types of mimetypes at the same time, and was curious if someone had done that before, because the project requires doing that without third party apps!